# How do I return None if ORM model class is invalid in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to validate a field of an ORM model when it's created. If it is valid I would like it to return the model object. If it fails it will return None. My current approach is to use the `__new__` method and carry out the checks there. But I seem to be getting some errors when doing so with a model class that inherits from `Base`. Here is my code:

```
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __new__(cls, name: str) -> Thing:
        """
        Validates input before creating instance
        :param name: Thing name. E.g. orange, banana
        """
        is_valid = cls.check_if_valid_name(name)
        if is_valid:
            instance = super(Thing, cls).__new__(cls)
            instance.name = name
            return instance
        else:
            return None
```

I find it quite hard to debug SQLAlchemy. But it looks like the error is occuring when I am assigning a value to the name field. I'm guessing because whatever SqlAlchemy is doing under the hood hasn't run yet, so the field hasn't been registered properly before assignment. Has anyone managed to implement something similar? If so what was your approach?

Comment: It should work if you remove `instance.name = name`.  That part can be handled by the initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `None` from the constructor (`__new__`) of a class is a monumentally bad idea and design choice. You expect two things from invoking a constructor:

1. Either getting an instance of the class or
2. getting an exception raised.

If you want validation checks, run them in the initializer (`__init__`) and throw e.g. a `ValueError` if they fail. Then the caller can take approriate action, such as defaulting a variable to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've added a function to handle the validation and initialization of the model.

```
def make_thing(name):
    if check_if_valid_name(name):
        thing = Thing(name=name)
    else:
        return None
```